# Attempting to order table multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I am trying to group multiple rows and order it by the total values but im struggling to figure out whats going wrong.

```
Name       Total
=======    =======
ASOS        222
Tesco       11
ASOS        11111
Tesco       123
```

The table should look like this

```
Name       Total
=======    =======
ASOS        11111
ASOS        222
Tesco       123
Tesco       11
```

I thought this query would work

```
select * from tablename order by name asc, total asc
```

But that shows a result in the wrong order.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the datatype of `Total` ?

Comment: `select * from table order by name , total desc` , should do the job

Comment: Given what the OP is actually after, this is an appallingly bad example. (I want to use a stronger word, but decorum prohibits it)

Comment: Is your question about -just forgetting- `desc` to use in your query ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * from tablename order by total desc
```

Selecting two things to ORDER BY doesn't work too well if you're not familiar with ORDER BY syntax. from your description, it looks like you just want the highest total at the top. This query will order the results by total descending (highest first)

if you want the names to be ascending (lowest first) at the same time, try

```
select * from tablename order by name asc, total desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried that already but i also want to order by the highest urls. Asos should always appear at the top because it has the highest value. I think i might need to use the group by function

Comment: If the fact that there are multiples of each name is unnecessary you might want to try something like 

    `select distinct name, sum(total) as total from tablename group by name order by total desc`

Answer (score 0):

First order by the max total for each name, descending, the order by total descending:

```
select *
from tablename t1
order by (select max(total) from tablename t2
          where t1.name = t2.name) desc,
         total desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY
    Name,
    char_length(CAST(Total As varchar(max))) DESC,
    Total DESC
```